# Why am I not being able to compile SASS with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

I have the following modules in my Webpack config:

```
module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

You can see that I am using sass-loader, and for *.scss files I am defining this pipeline: `['style', 'css', 'sass']`.

Then I have my scss file:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

(...)
```

Finally I have my HTML page (in a VUE file from vue.js) which imports that scss file:

```
<script>

require('./styles/main.scss')

(...)

</script>
```

**But somehow I get this error when launching the project:**

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module build failed:
html {
^
      Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in /Users/td/uprank/src/styles/main.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./src/styles/main.scss 4:14-247 13:2-17:4 14:20-253
```

Why is it getting the pipeline wrong? (It appears webpack is trying to process `['css', 'sass', 'style', 'css', 'sass']` instead of just `['style', 'css', 'sass']` as configured in modules.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Link to the full example project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1066659/dummy.zip

Comment: `require('./styles/main.scss')` shoud not come inside `<script>` tag.

instead it should be inside `<style lang="sass"></style>` using sass import syntax.

Comment: I compiles now without showing errors. However the CSS is not rendered into the resulting page (i.e. is not getting included in the html).

Comment: I added a link to the full project.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because Vue automatically generates loader configurations for CSS, SASS/SCSS, Stylus.

(See `projectRoot/build/utils.js` lines ~10 through ~50)

So you're seeing the error because you have a webpack loader that is attempting to import the file and then Vue is attempting to import the (already loaded) file. So you can think of your loader chain as `sass -> css -> style -> sass -> css -> vue-style`

In order to resolve this issue you have to get rid of the loader that you added:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
},
```

and just rely on the provided loader.

You can load your stylesheet in one of two ways:

> NOTE: You **MUST** use `scss` instead of `sass`, as `sass` will attempt to parse your stylesheet using the indented syntax instead of the bracket syntax.

1:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './styles/main.scss
</style>
```

2:

```
<style src="./styles/main.scss"></style>
```

Both of these will import the stylesheet, the latter just prevents you from adding any additional styling to the component.

Comment: Quick addendum to the last paragraph: You can use multiple `<style>` tags in a .vue component, so while you cannot add any CSS rules to the tag with the `src` attribute, you can add a second tag and put them in there.

Comment: You save my day!

Comment: What if I want to import scss file in JS file?

Comment: @TaylorGlaeser - do you mean Vue is trying to determine the loaders, or do you mean Vue-cli?