# how to import all css of node_modules in vuejs

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, node-modules, vue-cli

I am building a Vue.js app starting with the webpack template and vuetify.
To import vuetify css Im doing this in my **App.vue**

`<style>
    @import '../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
</style>`

Is this the correct or only way? because it doesn't seem reliable when using multiple UI components.

Comment: While @vamsi's answer provides the syntax for the import, I found I did not need to modify the webpack configuration. Doing so led to compilation errors. See here for the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031123/why-am-i-not-being-able-to-compile-sass-with-webpack

Answer (score 54):

You can import it in yout **main.js**

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

for this to work you should have `css-loader` in you webpack config

In your **webpack**

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" }
  ]
}
```

**OR**

In your **App.vue** component add two style tags , one for global styles as **App.vue**  is the entry point and other for scoped styles if you have any with the scoped attribute.See [src imports](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#src-imports).

```
<style src='vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
    /* global styles */
</style> 

<style scoped>
    /* local styles */
</style>
```