# Cannot Export Sass Variables into Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass

I'm trying to export the following SASS variables into Javascript within my Vue project.

`_export.sass`

```
:export
    colorvariable: blue
    othercolorvariable: red
```

I'm following the response in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536228/export-sass-scss-variables-to-javascript-without-exporting-them-to-css) as a template. However when I try to import my sass file below...

`About.vue`

```
<script>
import styles from "@/styles/_export.sass";

export default {
    name: "About",
    data() {
        return { styles };
    }
};
</script>
```

I receive the following error:

```
WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                 2:17:03 AM

98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                             2:17:03 AM

 error  in ./src/styles/_export.sass

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after '...les/main.sass";': expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "export: {"
        on line 1 of /Users/MatthewBell/GitHub/pollify/client/src/styles/_export.sass
>> @import "@/styles/main.sass";

   -----------------------------^


 @ ./src/styles/_export.sass 4:14-227 14:3-18:5 15:22-235
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/About.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/About.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/About.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.37:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

If I remove `import styles from "@/styles/_export.sass";` the code compiles fine.

I've researched this error and found [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031123/why-am-i-not-being-able-to-compile-sass-with-webpack) which seems to imply that my Vue config file is not set correctly. Here is my `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/styles/main.sass"`
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Note that `main.sass` referenced above does not import `_export.sass`. And again, this has worked fine for me until I tried importing `_export.sass` into my JS file.

I want to import `_export.sass` variables into the JS script, as shown above, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sass imports must always be a relative import. Webpack knows that you mean your src folder with the '@' (probably because of an alias setting somewhere) and replaces them in JS files on compilation, but can't do that for your sass. Changing that might make your import statement valid.

Comment: That import works though... It's the import line that tries to import 'styles' in 'about.vue' which causes the error. If I remove that, the other import works fine

Comment: It's even mentioned in the docs that I can use @ in the config file specifically, don't think that's the issue

Comment: Ah, when I tried to use prependData for vuetify's sass variable import that was one of the caveats I ran into, but I'm using a non-Vue CLI webpack config.

The only situation I can think of otherwise is that it could be the order that your loaders are in, because seems it's already transformed once it's handed to sass-loader (I think this because of the presence of the semicolon and the bracket). I hope others may have a more certain answer!

Comment: I agree I also thought it has to do with the loader order but can't seem to fix it

Comment: @Matt - Just to cancel out the obvious, can you add semicolons to the end of your variable statements in `_export.scss` and then test?

Comment: Do you mean `:export
    colorvariable: blue;
    othercolorvariable: red;`

Comment: Just realised you are using SASS, not SCSS. Is there any reason why? I would advise using SCSS instead as the format matches CSS. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: @Matt - yes, I did mean that but as you are using SASS, I am not sure if that will fix it. I have always used SCSS

Comment: I've just always preferred the simplicity of the SASS, I'll try SCSS and report back

Comment: The purpose of SCSS is to offer the functionality of SASS, whilst also maintaining the format of CSS. Theoretically, you can copy and paste CSS into a SCSS file and it will work, whereas SASS requires syntax changes

Comment: ```Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: media query expression must begin with '('
        on line 2 of /Users/MatthewBell/GitHub/pollify/client/src/styles/_export.scss
>> :export {```

Comment: After changing it to `_export.scss` and the contents to ```:export {
 colorvariable: blue;
 colortwovariable: red;
}```

Comment: I have never used SASS so I cannot be certain about the following but I believe that your issue lies in the fact that either the `export` statement is not syntactically correct, or SASS does not support this feature. As your `prependData` seems to work fine, I do not think this is an issue with the loader (although the test will need to be updated to `.scss`)

Comment: Another thing you can try is commenting the import in JS, and import `_export.sass` into `main.sass` just to see if it compiles. This will let us narrow things down

Comment: Just tried that, it did not compile, throwing the error: ```Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "e": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "export: {"
        on line 1 of src/styles/_export.sass
        from line 5 of src/styles/main.sass
        from line 1 of /Users/MatthewBell/GitHub/pollify/client/src/views/Home.vue
>> export: {```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212986/discussion-between-matt-and-ben-carey).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately the SASS/SCSS documentation does not mention anything about `export`, and as such, other than guessing and solving it through trial and error, your best bet is to migrate to SCSS and implement the solution that is widely used (but also not documented).

Personally, I like to import my SCSS variables, and then, export them to JS. So my `_export.scss` file looks like this:

```
@import "variables";

:export {

    // Export the color palette to make it accessible to JS
    some-light-blue: $some-light-blue;
    battleship-grey: $battleship-grey;
    // etc...

}
```

**NOTE:** It is vitally important that `_export.scss` is only utilised in JS files, and is not imported in SCSS files. Importing `_export.scss` into your SCSS files will result in a) unecessary style exports in your CSS, and b) duplications of these style exports throughout every compiled SCSS file

Comment: is it possible to get this to work with Rollup as well?

Comment: @SergevandenOever I'm asking myself the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588047/rollup-allow-export-statement-in-scss-file-to-import-in-js

Comment: I think it is undocumented because it is not a Sass feature but a css-modules one called [ICSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss) that works with the css-loader with Webpack

Comment: When I use `:export` in one of my SCSS files, I get an webpack error: "Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token" using sass-loader@13.0.2_sass@1.54.4+webpack@5.74.0 in an Angular / TS app. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: It does work with Rollup, as long as the `:export` rule is in a file named `*.module.scss` rather than `*.scss`. However, it would be useful to be able to exclude such files from css bundle compilation. (To avoid the inclusion of rules like `:export { /* the exports ... */ }` in the compiled css.) Does anyone know how to do that with Vite/Rollup?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in you [Vue SFC styles block](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules), which [would look something like](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/vue.js-scoped-styles-vs-css-modules) this:

```
<template>
  <button :class="$style.button" />
</template>

<style module>
  .button {
    color: red
  }
</style>
```

Also please note that often times people are talking about using Sass, but in actuality they are or should be using `.scss` file type, which is the modern syntax compared to older `.sass`, but its a matter of taste really.

Comment: Ah this is very interesting. Thank you for adding this in, I didn't know this was possible!

Answer (score 1):

global.scss

```
$primary-color: #d51a1a; //Red

:export {
  appColor: $primary-color;
}
```

app.vue

```
import variables from '../global.scss'
```

you can access it by using :

```
variables.locals.appColor
```

Comment: The initial question was asking how to do this in SASS, not SCSS