# Rollup - Allow :export statement in scss file to import in js

Tags: sass, rollupjs, sass-loader, rollup-plugin-postcss, icss

We have a Vue component library built with Rollup. The development is in early stage but everything worked well so far besides this one thing: we are not able to export SASS variables from a scss file and import them in a js file. We are used to do it using the `:export` statement of Webpack `sass-loader`. Something like this:

*breakpoint.scss*

```
@import './unit.scss';

$breakpoint-mobile: 360px;
$breakpoint-tablet: 768px;
$breakpoint-desktop: 1200px;

:export {
  mobile: strip-unit($breakpoint-mobile);
  tablet: strip-unit($breakpoint-tablet);
  desktop: strip-unit($breakpoint-desktop);
}
```

then in any js file, we could import the stylesheet `import breakpoints from '@/styles/settings/breakpoints.scss'` where `breakpoints` will be equal to `{ mobile: '360', tablet: '768', desktop: '1200' }`.

So it works fine with Webpack, but I can't get it working with Rollup using [rollup-plugin-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-styles) without additional config (I also tried [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss), same result). I also can't find anything on Google related to that issue...

This is the result of *breakpoints.scss* compiled by Rollup:

```
import n from '../../node_modules/rollup-plugin-styles/dist/runtime/inject-css.js';

var css = ":export{mobile:360;tablet:768;desktop:1200;}";
n(css,{});

export default css;
export { css };
//# sourceMappingURL=breakpoints.scss.js.map
```

So it seems like it wants to inject the styles which makes sense, but still not the behavior I want. Is it already possible to achieve what I'm looking for or I need to contribute to `rollup-plugin-styles` to add the support?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: it looks like this is supported, please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68590252/1280867) provided by pmrotule.

**Old answer**:
The feature you are referring to is [Interoperable CSS (ICSS)](https://github.com/css-modules/icss).
As you have stated, the popular [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) for webpack-based projects supports it.
As far as I can tell [rollup-plugin-styles](https://github.com/Anidetrix/rollup-plugin-styles) does currently not support *Interoperable CSS*. This is one of the reasons I still use webpack for my projects.

There is an [open issue for this feature](https://github.com/Anidetrix/rollup-plugin-styles/issues/165).

Contributing to the project and adding support for ICSS is a great idea, but expect some discussion about how the configuration will look like.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for referencing the issue on Github, I'll continue the conversation there.

Comment: It seems that these days, at least with the default configuration used by Vite for Rollup, all that is required is to name the file that contains the exports `*.module.scss` instead of just `*.scss`. However, a related issue is, how do I prevent the compiled css bundle from containing a useless css rule that looks like `:export { /* all the exports ... */ }`? I would like to put all exports in a `*.module.scss` that is excluded from the css bundle, but even if I never import anything from the file, it is included in the bundle by virtue of simply existing in the source tree.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that if I use the option `modules: true` of [rollup-plugin-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-styles), I get the behavior I was looking for... More details in the [README](https://github.com/Anidetrix/rollup-plugin-styles#css-modules).